# WebRTC passing a flag between clients

Tags: webrtc

We have an app where two users are connected to each other through webrtc.
During the call, a prompt will appear on each their device to go to the next screen which will start a timer.
What we want is both buttons prompts to be pressed so the timer can start at the same time on both devices.

Is there a way of sending custom data like a flag between each client when a button has been pressed?

Answer (score 1):

I think you want to use [Data Channels](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/WebRTC_API/Using_data_channels)

WebRTC allows the exchange of binary (or text) data between two peers. I am not exactly sure what 'a flag' will be, but hopefully that works!